# Launch NeoMAD application with emulator

Tags: android, neomad

I am trying to launch one of their examples for android to test it on emulator, so i opened eclipse, and installed the NeoMAD plugin,then add the emulator genymotion (Name: Genymotion / Location: http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse)

However when I try to launch it for ANDROID 
I get an error:

> com.neomades.neomad.ideconnector.PluginConnector.getProject(Ljava/io/File;)Lcom/neomades/neomad/ide/IProject;

although the apk file was generated by NeoMAD but it doesn't launch also the source code was not generated.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have the latest NeoMAD version (3.7.1) released on 01/30/2015 because the previous version (3.7.0) have a launch simulator bug. And it could be the problem you talk about.

NeoMAD can deploy application on simulator or device if it is detected by ADB, so you should not have any problem if your simulator is already launched.

To generate a project:

- right click on your NeoMAD project
- NeoMAD Tools -> Generate project

Cheers

Comment: I update the neomad plugin version 3.7.1 and the simulator is detected by ADB So I launched my emulator with the ADT and then I launched the application and it has not launched in the emulator in the Console i have this: Unable to launch the Android Application : Please make sure that your ADT Plugin is up to date. although my ADT version is 23.0.2.1 I have the same problem with the NeoMAD bundle

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday with NeoMAD, I updated eclipse ADT Plugin with the "Check for update" entry in Help menu. It has updated my ADT plugin, then when I restarded Eclipse it worked. For information my ADT plugin version is 23.0.4.14, and in Android SDK Manager my Android SDK Tool version is 24.0.2.

Comment: i updated my ADT plugin to the version 23.0.4.14

And problem was solved
thank you